# PHP variable reference puzzle

Tags: php, reference

run following code:

```
<?php
$a = array('yes');
$a[] = $a;
var_dump($a);
```

out put:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "yes"
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "yes"
  }
}
```

run following code:

```
<?php
$a = array('no');
$b = &$a;
$a[] = $b;
$a = array('yes');
$a[] = $a;
var_dump($a);
```

out put:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "yes"
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "yes"
    [1]=>
    *RECURSION*
  }
}
```

I have reassigned value of $a, why there are *RECURSION* circular references?

Comment: Wow, something interesting on stackoverflow! :). +1!!!

Answer (score 3):

To remove reference you need to call `unset`. Without `unset` after `$a = array('yes');` `$a` still bounds with `$b` and they are still references. So the second part has the same behavior as first one.

> Note, however, that references inside arrays are potentially
>   dangerous. Doing a normal (not by reference) assignment with a
>   reference on the right side does not turn the left side into a
>   reference, but references inside arrays are preserved in these normal
>   assignments.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php